# Why do my module cloud logger logs not appear in Google Cloud Logging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

When logging from a module logger inside Google Cloud Functions the logs are not stored in Google Cloud Logging when the Cloud Function is invoked. The logger from the Python **logging** module uses the integration with Google Cloud Logging as shown [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/stdlib-usage.html#).

I have created a sample code to illustrate this behaviour. The main.py file is the following:

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler


client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name='module_logger_log')
module_logger = logging.getLogger('module_logger')
module_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
module_logger.addHandler(handler)
module_logger.info('log info: module_logger created')


def cf_endpoint(req):
    # Testing all severities
    module_logger.debug('log debug')
    module_logger.info('log info')
    module_logger.warning('log warning')
    module_logger.error('log error')
    module_logger.critical('log critical')

    return 'ok'
```

The deployment is HTTP triggered, uses Python 3.8, the entry point is the function `cf_endpoint` and the requirements.txt file is the following:

```
google-cloud-logging==2.0.2
```

The logs stored in Google Cloud Logging from the deployment and triggering of the code can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNKh1.png). As it can be appreciated the log from the deployment appears, but the logs from the entry point are not present.

Has anyone experienced this kind of buggy behaviour or am I overlooking something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to open an  [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)  as that would allow GCP support to pass this on to the appropriate teams in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already opened an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176570488). I'll further update this post if I get an answer from GCP support.